# Synonyms for "rather"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

For instance, when I was asked which I would like to have intelligence or creativity if I had to choose (it was a wierd question though), I answered, like "Well, I think intelligence and creativity are somewhat related. Rather, creativity can be just one type of intelligence."

I have been always use "rather" for those contexts.
Could you tell me some synonyms or more suitable words for "rather", if any?

Comment: I would have expected _rather_ to be in the question! (_Would you rather have A or B?_) _In fact_ would be more appropriate in your answer.

Comment: I think in this context, where you are using "rather" to precede a correction or improvement, you might want "Better".

Comment: Or "In fact, creativity can be..."

Comment: [Rather](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rather) can mean "somewhat" or "preferably", so it can be used to state something better or something not as good. Which is intended here?

Comment: @StuartF I intend to clarify or correct my former sentence. So, like Kate Bunting mentioned above, now I guess "in fact" is more appropriate here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Well, I think intelligence and creativity are somewhat related.
> Rather, creativity can be just one type of intelligence.

As written, that means something like:

> Well, I think … .
> No, actually I mean … .

The second sentence *corrects* the first, and (unless you were trying for rhetorical effect) the whole thing is equivalent to the single sentence:

> Well, I think creativity can be just one type of intelligence.

But you could have said:

> Well, I think … .
> Specifically, creativity … .

In this case, the second sentence *tightens* the meaning of the vague "somewhat" in the first sentence without contradicting it.
The listener gets the general idea from the first sentence, and then within that context, the second sentence provides your real point.

Both usages are grammatically correct, but at most one of them matches your intended meaning.

Answer (score 2):

In the introductory sentence, stating "I think" appropriately acknowledges that you are expressing an opinion. By choosing to use a separate sentence for stating *creativity can be just one type of intelligence* you infer a special emphasis, but introducing it with "Rather" adds an ambiguity to your sentence. Because  I ask "Rather what?", are you stating a fact, or are you adding to your original opinion?. But, "Rather, in fact", or simply, "In fact" would be inappropriate because the statement is not qualified with evidence of its truth value, in fact it is not a fact.

Therefore, I suggest  that "Rather,  I believe", or simply "I believe" would be appropriate and would complement the first sentence -